# Repeated class qualifier is accepted. Why?

Tags: c++

A colleague sent me code similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Weird
{
public:
    Weird();
};

Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird::Weird()
{
    std::cout << "Ok, this is weird.\n";
}

int main()
{
    Weird a;
}
```

It compiles and runs and produces "Ok, this is weird." I tried it with g++, clang, and msvc with online compilers and it works on all of them.

Why is the repeated class name qualifier accepted? Is this intended by the standard?

Comment: This is a dupe, I'll have a target in a minute

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica: Thanks. I tried to find one and didn't, so I asked. Some questions are just darn hard to search.

Comment: No worries.  Unless you know the term, it's hard to find

Comment: I'll leave this up. Maybe it'll make it easier for someone else to find.

Comment: @FredLarson Which is exactly what you're supposed to do with duplicates. Duplicates are good for the stack, they help with SEO.